# Mapping variables to a specific address in C

Tags: c, pointers

I want to set a few variables in my program (meant for integrated ARC core in SoC) to a specific address. I use this syntax:

```
#define PORTBASE 0x00C07F00

volatile Uint32* Ptr = (Uint32*)PORTBASE; //Uint32 is defined elsewhere
*Ptr = 0xA5A5A5A5;
```

*Uint definition:

```
typedef unsigned long Uint32;
```

However, the A5 data is not being written to `0x00C0_7F00`. Instead, the core attempts to write to this address: `0x00C0_DC00`, which causes an interrupt since it's not a supported address. The `0x00C07F00` represents a specific register mapped to that address.

Can anyone think of a reason why the address is changed?

Comment: never tried that one before, but i wonder - if you change PORTBASE? will the cpu try to write with the same shift? maybe pointer addresses are automaticly changed to fit inside some range.

Comment: 1) Use standard types for fixed bit-width, not some homebrew stuff. 2) Using an intermediate variable is useless. 3) see [ask].

Comment: The standard specifies that "An integer may be converted to any  pointer type.   Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation" (C2011 6.3.2.3/5).  Basically, that means you need to consult the docs for your compiler for what result to expect from a conversion such as you are performing, and for how to get the result you want, if that's possible at all.  And if the compiler conforms, then its docs *will* say.

Comment: 1) Suspicious of `Uint32`, post its definition.  2) Shot-in the-dark: try `(Uint32*)((char *)PORTBASE)`.  Perhaps some _interesting_ pointer math in converting the integer to a `Uint32` pointer.

Comment: Added Uint32 definition.

Comment: @chux, if you think I didn't ask the question well, I'd be happy to get constructive criticism regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

What is your environment (Bare-Metal, Linux, Windows ,...)?

If you use a OS like Linux, the address should be relative to your process pointer. In Linux you can use [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to translate your address.

A simple example is [devmem](http://free-electrons.com/pub/mirror/devmem2.c).

As Bare-Metal application use fixed standard types as mentioned before in the comments.

Comment: Your reference to `mmap()` is a bit of a non-sequitur.  The thing that makes the example you linked work is Linux's `/dev/mem` device; `mmap()` just makes that more convenient to work with.  Therefore, inasmuch as `/dev/mem` is an OS facility, not a C facility, it's a bit questionable to call this a C solution.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around for a bit, I found a workaround, although I'm not sure exactly why it worked:
Instead of trying to cast the address as it's defined. I first assign it to a const variable, and then I cast that variable to be a pointer:

```
#define PORTBASE 0x00C07F00
const Uint32 PortOpCodeAddr = PORTBASE;
Uint32* volatile const PortOpCode = (Uint32*)PortOpCodeAddr;
```